# R find the states, cities from a dataframe with Long and Lat

Tags: r, maps, latitude-longitude

I have one datafame (X) with:

Columns Names:   City,UF, Longitude,Latitude

And the second (Y) with:

Columns Names: Longitude, Latitude

I need to get the City and UF for each "Longitude, Latitude" in Y dataframe.

Thank you!

Comment: Do the longitute and latitude values exactly match in both tables? Then a simple `merge()` ought to do the trick. Without a [reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) it's hard to say for sure.

Comment: they are X (x$city,x$uf,x$lon,x$lat) and Y(y$lon,y$lat)

Comment: and they have different number of rows

Comment: Did you try `merge(X,Y)`?

Comment: data <- merge(y=Y, x=X, by.y=c("lon","lat"), by.x=c("lon","lat"))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As long as your column names match, you can do a simple merge to join the values of Y with X.

```
merge(X,Y)
```

That will pull all the values of X that have a matching latitude and longitude in Y.